# Spring Security OAuth2 - URLEncoded input Key-Values getting auto-appended in token response json

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring-Security OAuth2 - Password Grant to obtain JWT Access and Refresh tokens.

I am passing a few additional URLEncoded Key/Values in the request to /oauth/token - so that i can add them as additional claims in the generated JWT Access and Refresh Tokens.

TokenEnhancer is adding them as additional claims in the generated JWT Access and Refresh Tokens; but problem is these get also added in the Response JSON as well - which i don't want to. 
How to prevent it getting appended in response?

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
                .secret(passwordEncoder().encode(CLIENT_SECRET))
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();     
        converter.setAccessTokenConverter( new JwtConverter() );
        converter.setSigningKey("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserAttributesMap userAttributesMapper() {
        return new UserAttributesMap();
    }

    public static class JwtConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter implements JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void configure(JwtAccessTokenConverter converter) {
            converter.setAccessTokenConverter(this);
        }

        @Override
        public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
            OAuth2Authentication auth = super.extractAuthentication(map);
            auth.setDetails(map);
            return auth;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

    @Autowired
    private UserAttributesMap userAttributesMap;

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken, OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        additionalInfo.put("DateOfBirth", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("dob"));
        additionalInfo.put("PAN_Number", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("pan"));
        additionalInfo.put("Address_Line_1", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("addr1"));
        additionalInfo.put("Address_Line_2", oAuth2Authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("addr2"));
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) oAuth2AccessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return oAuth2AccessToken;
    }
}
```

[Postman Request and Response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5tNi.png)

Comment: By default the `OAuth2AccessToken` is serialized by Jackson and `additionalInfo` is serialized, too. You could change your serializer.

Comment: have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: Why don't you want them in the response? They're easily decoded from the JWT tokens anyway (unless you have an encrypted token.)

Comment: Hi Dur, Many thanks!! That worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution advised by @dur worked...